# R-Caret equivalent of Scikit-Learn's DummyClassifier?

Tags: r, scikit-learn, r-caret

What R-Caret method can be used to generate random classification guesses and determine whether they're classified correctly? I've used DummyClassifier as a model comparison in the past, but I'd like to stick to Caret here.

Comment: If you have a binary classification problem, why not start by assuming that a random classifier would have a 50% accuracy? The `ROCR` package has a lot of great tools for testing classifiers.

Comment: sample() below is most likely the closest, you just need to specify probs = .. based on whether you need "frequent", "stratified", "uniform"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sample()` function to do that which is nice because it allows you to control what the distribution of "classifications" should look like.